# Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Searched and searched on SO and can't figure it out
Tried CASTING each field as FLOAT to no avail, convert didn't get me any further
How can I get the below case clause to return the value stated in the THEN section?

Error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.

section of my SQL query that makes it error:

```
When cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code like '%[%]%' and (prod.dbo.BTYS2012.average_days_pay) - (substring(cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code,3,2)) <= 5 THEN prod.dbo.cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code
```

average_days_pay = float
terms_code = char

Cheers!

Comment: Please post a sample of the data for the two fields used in your query.

Comment: The thing is in substring(cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code,3,2) expression contain improper value for convert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to handle strings which can't be converted:

```
When cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code like '%[%]%' 
and (prod.dbo.BTYS2012.average_days_pay) - 

(case when isnumeric(substring(cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code,3,2))=1 
         then cast(substring(cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code,3,2) as float)
         else 0
 end)
<= 5 THEN prod.dbo.cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue that you're having is that you're specifically searching for strings that contain a `%` character, and then converting them (implicitly or explicitly) to float.

But strings containing `%` signs can't be converted to float whilst they still have a `%` in them. This also produces an error:

```
select CONVERT(float,'12.5%')
```

If you're wanting to convert to float, you'll need to remove the `%` sign first, something like:

```
CONVERT(float,REPLACE(terms_code,'%',''))
```

will just eliminate it. I'm not sure if there are any other characters in your `terms_code` column that may also trip it up.

You also need to be aware that SQL Server can quite aggressively re-order operations and so may attempt the above conversion on other strings in `terms_code`, even those not containing `%`. If that's the source of your error, then you need to prevent this aggressive re-ordering. Provided there are no aggregates involved, a `CASE` expression can usually avoid the worst of the issues - make sure that all strings that you don't want to deal with are eliminated by earlier `WHEN` clauses before you attempt your conversion

Comment: Posted some sample data - doesn't seem like I can change the percent sign :/

Comment: @user2086052 - just for future reference, don't post sample data in comments - *edit* your question. You can then use the tools there to *format* the data so that we can actually read it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

If your are sure that Substring Part returns a numeric value, You can Cast The substring(....) to Float :

```
 .....and (prod.dbo.BTYS2012.average_days_pay) - (CAST(substring(cust_trendd_w_costsv.terms_code,3,2)) as float ) <= 5 ....
```

Comment: Sample Data  
terms_code: 
NULL
1%1030
1%1560
1%30  
1%3045
1%45  
2%1030
2%1045
2%1060
CA    
CC    
DUR   
LEGALA
NET10 
NET30 
NET45 
NET60


average_days_pay:
0
46.975
46.5555555555556
32.2
123.5
65.625
40.75
54.6
95.3333333333333
126.666666666667
14.741935483871
54.7894736842105
44.6153846153846
31.2307692307692
77.9583333333333
57.5
33.8829268292683
67.75