# "Error converting data type varchar to float": how to get around this error in my SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varchar

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
USE MyDatabase

;with cte1 as (    
    SELECT ID, Name, Age
    from [Table1]    
    Where ([Age] is NOT NULL OR [Age] >= 18)
),    
cte2 as 
(
    Select *,    
        (case when [Age] between 18 and 24 then '18 - 24'
         when [Age] between 25 and 35 then '25 - 35'
         when [Age] between 36 and 45 then '36 - 45'
         when [Age] between 46 and 55 then '18 - 24'
         when [Age] between 56 and 65 then '18 - 24'
         when [Age] > 65 then 'Above 65'
         ELSE [Age]
         END) as [Age Group]    
    from [cte1]    
)    
SELECT *
from [cte2]
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I know the error has to do with my [Age] `case expression` because when I remove that `case expression` from the query, it runs fine.

Note: the [Age] column in my table has its type as `float` and contains NULLs.

I have tried the answer provided here and I am still getting the same error message: [Error converting data type varchar to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952004/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-float)

How can I get around this error?

Comment: And why are you using a float for age? In fact why would you even store age? Surely you would store a date and calculate age?

Comment: "Note: the [Age] column in my table *has its type as float* and contains NULLs." - the OP claims not to be, which seems dubious. However, it should be challenged *as presented*.

Comment: @DaleK I get a syntax error when I remove that semi-colon

Comment: @user3115933 The entire debacle above was to **move** the semi-colon (a preferential placement), *not remove*. "use ..; \n with" and "use .. \n ; with" are the same effect.

Comment: @Dalek I didn't create that Table. I am working with an existing table.

Comment: @DaleK FWIW I always lead my CTEs with `;` because inevitably someone will copy just that statement into their own code (with no statement terminators) and then **I** get the crap for it. Ask me how I know (and why I've been [pushing for better practices for over 11 years now](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)). You can put 50 semi-colons between two statements and it is the same as one, so other than style points, having a safety semi-colon prefix a statement that starts with a massively overloaded keyword causes no harm.

Comment: @DaleK Purists don't like that I do that for insurance purposes but, well, purists don't sign my paycheck, so... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case expression needs all return types to be the same. You have mixed up strings and floats. Convert the float to a string and it works.

```
CASE WHEN [Age] BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18 - 24'
WHEN [Age] between 25 and 35 THEN '25 - 35'
WHEN [Age] between 36 and 45 THEN '36 - 45'
WHEN [Age] between 46 and 55 THEN '18 - 24'
WHEN [Age] between 56 and 65 THEN '18 - 24'
WHEN [Age] > 65 THEN 'Above 65'
-- Conversion required here
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), [Age])
END AS [Age Group]
```

Note: I assume there is more to your query than you have posted, otherwise there is no reason to have 2 CTE's.

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` expression mixes results of different types, float and text. This doesn't work in SQL, where each query/statement has to return a single type.

SQL Server will try to convert all values to a single type using the [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rules, preferring more specific over more general types. `float` has higher precedence than `varchar` so the server will try to cast all values to `float` and fail.

The `ELSE` clause will have to return a `varchar` instead, eg:

```
ELSE cast(Ages as varchar(4))
```